# Question about measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

I am reading through a proof in Royden and it seems he has skipped/assume a step, and I am trying to figure out why it is true. Nevertheless, I think it is because of the following, if it is true.

**Question:**
Suppose that $f:E \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ such that $m(E) = 0$. Is $f$ automatically a measurable function?

I would assume this is true. Moreover, $f:E \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a measurable function if
$E$ is measurable and for each real number $c$, the set $\{x \in E: f(x) > c\}$ is measurable. Obviously, $m(E) = 0$ implies that $E$ is measurable, and $\{x \in E: f(x) > c\} \subseteq E$ implies that $\{x \in E: f(x) > c\}$ is measurable, hence, the statement should be true, correct?

Comment: yes............

Comment: The definition of measurable function is not related to the measure itself but with the $\sigma$-algebra of $E$